# How to make query for table with column contains Pointer value?

Tags: android, kotlin, parse-platform

I have object called `Reservation` which contains column with name `"object_entity"` and inside is `ParseObject` from table `Entity`. I want to query only those `Reservation` which contains certain `Entity`.

```
val q = ParseQuery.getQuery<ParseObject>("Reservation")
if (!isOnline(c)){
   q.ignoreACLs()
   q.fromLocalDatastore()
}

q.whereEqualTo("object_entity", ticket.getParseObject("object_entity")?.objectId)

q.findInBackground { itemList, err ->
    itemList //empty size 0
    err //null
}
```

This is working as intended if you are online. But if you are offline it will return empty list. I've checked local datastore and all expected objects are there. But if I remove q.whereEqualTo it will return list of all Reservations without any problem (but I need specific ones).

`ticket.getParseObject("object_entity")?.objectId` is not null. It always contains objectId - checked in debugger

If I remove q.whereEqualTo I check all returned Reservation objects if they contains Entity.

This is inside findInBackground:

```
itemList.forEach { reservation ->
    val entityObj = reservation.getParseObject("object_entity")
     if (entityObj == null) createLog("FoundObj", "null") else
         createLog("FoundObj", entityObj.objectId.toString())
}
```

Ive tried to add inside q.whereEqualTo specific Entity objectId. And it returned empty list. But if I removed q.whereEqualTo that specific object with specific objectId I wanted to get was returned in list.

Comment: Can you check and make sure that `ticket.getParseObject("object_entity")?.objectId` has a value also when you are offline?

Comment: Also, try: `q.whereEqualTo("object_entity", ParseObject.createWithoutData("Entity", ticket.getParseObject("object_entity")?.objectId))`

Comment: objectId is not null in offline

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?